# Image hover not working

Tags: html, css, image, mousehover

I have created an image map with a couple of area's.

When I hover over a specific area, it should show a stamp on top of it.
This works perfect in Chrome, but not in Firefox or IE.

Any advice why this doesn't work? 
HTML:

```
<area class="name sold" 
      shape="poly" 
      coords="121,282,101,277,93,259,93,231,103,212,131,207,157,229,149,272," 
      href="#" alt="" title="" />
```

CSS:

```
.name 
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 225px;
    left: 50px;
    display: block;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    z-index: -100;
}
.name.sold:hover 
{
    background-image: url('sold.png');
    background-position: 0 0;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    z-index: 100;
}
.name.sale:hover 
{
    background-image: url('forsale.png');
    background-position: 0 0;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

The area works, but it just doesn't do anything when hovering over it.

Live example here:
http://jonasgeuens.be/test/

Comment: Unless you have a typo (or have omitted something) in your CSS, the name.sale part won't work without positioning (relative or absolute). Might that be the cause?

Comment: I'm sorry, that was indeed a typo and should just be .name {...

Comment: Do you have some live code we can see?

Comment: Might just be a relative url problem with the css (are `sold.png` and `forsale.png` in the same folder as your css?) jsfiddle with different png [here](http://jsfiddle.net/thwp6/1/)

Comment: I have added a live example. Both images are in the same folder. Keep in mind that everything works perfect in Chrome, it just doesn't do anything in Firefox and IE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may be wrong but I don't think that image maps can do what you're trying to do here, i.e. place smaller images over the top of your original image map.

Normal practice here would be to probably use javascript.

Alternatively you could probably place your large image as a background on a DIV (or as a regular image with a low z-index) then place your links on top of it using absolute positioning and a higher z-index and display:block. Then on hover of those links you could show your small images.

Comment: That could be a possible solution but then I would lose the precision of the map. I have seen several maps doing what I want to achieve, so I think it should be possible but right now I'm also thinking it's an issue with the area:hover.

Comment: Can you provide an example link of ones you've seen?

Comment: In those examples he's using a varation on the method I mentioned above by using absolutely positioned links - not regular image maps.

Comment: I noticed and removed the link. I think I am going to rewrite the entire page and don't use the image map. Thanks